# Forcing update rendering of MX ProgressBar?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

Would anyone know a method (or trick) to force a rendering update to an MX ProgressBar in `manual` mode when using `setProgress`?

I have a situation with a block of code containing a couple of `for` loops which take a bit of time to complete. It would be tedious to unwrap this code to generate events, etc.

**Update**

Let me expand on this with a bit of pseudo code. I want to update the progress bar during operations on the contents of an array. THe `for` loops blocks so the screen isn't updating. I've tried `validateNow()` but that had no effect.

Is there some non-convoluted way I can either unwrap the `for` loop or use AS3's event model to update a progress bar? (I'm more accustomed to multi-threaded environments where this sort of task is trivial).

```
   private function doSomeWork():void {
       progressBar.visible = true;

       for(var n = 0; n < myArray.length; n++){

            progressBar.setProgress(n, myArray.length);
            progressBar.label = "Hello World " + n;
            progressBar.validateNow(); // this has no apparent effect

            var ba:ByteArray = someDummyFunction(myArray[i]);
            someOtherFunction(ba);
        }

         progressBar.visible = false;
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried [validateNow()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#validateNow()) ? Per description, it should redraw the component.

Comment: Hmm, it says it should be updated when you call `setProgress()` if the progress bar's control mode is `manual`. Probably you have cached its parent as bitmap? Or the mode got reset?

Comment: @DodgerThud - no joy. Have tried calling `progressBar.validateNow();` and `validateNow()` within the `ProgressBar` parent after calling `progressBar.setProgress(n1, n2)` and setting the `label` text but it never gets updated. Odd. Have encountered this before.

Comment: is your loop blocking the UI so no UI events can be handled? if yes you may need to split the long running job in smaller chunks

Comment: Check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120822/forcing-flex-to-update-the-screen

Answer (score 1):

In Flex, the screen is never updating while Actionscript code is running. It basically works like this:

1. Execute all runnable Actionscript code.
2. Update the screen.
3. Repeat continuously.

To learn more details, google for [flex elastic racetrack]. But the above is the nut of what you need to understand.

If you don't want a long-running piece of code to freeze the screen, you'll have to break it up into chunks and execute them across multiple frames, perhaps within a FRAME_ENTER event handler.

Comment: Or use an [Actionscript Worker](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is the problem. I tried the following code and it works without any need to `validateNow`.

```
  protected function button2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
        for(var n:int = 0; n < 100; n = n+20){
        progressBar.setProgress(n, 100);
        progressBar.label = "Hello World " + n;
        // progressBar.validateNow(); 
        }
  }
  <mx:VBox width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:ProgressBar id="progressBar"/>
        <mx:Button label="Update Progress" click="button2_clickHandler(event)"/>                
    </mx:VBox>
```