# Flex valuation of conditional expression issue (data binding ?)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, data-binding, actionscript

I'm in trouble with valuation of conditional expression in `Flex`.

Let me explain.

I have this :

```
    <s:Label text="SomeTextLawyer" includeInLayout="{Session.isLawyer()}"
 visible="{Session.isLawyer()}"/>
    <s:Label text="SomeTextDoctor" includeInLayout="{Session.isDoctor()}"
 visible="{Session.isDoctor()}"/>
```

This Session object is defined as below :

```
public class Session extends Singleton
{
    [Bindable]
    private static var user:User;

[...]

    public static function isDoctor():Boolean {
        return Session.user.type == model.type.DOCTOR;
    }

    public static function isLaywer():Boolean {
        return Session.user.type == model.type.LAWYER;
    }
}
```

I have a mechanism that change the user, so my user can be first a doctor and then a lawyer. Problem is that my labels keep their first valuation. If I connect as a doctor first, I still have the doctor label displayed if I change my user as a lawyer. And vice versa...

On the AS code, my user is the good kind of user, but not on my `mxml` files... So only the displayed part doesn't see the user switching.

Any idea ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: The method `isLawyer()` is not defined in the Session`` class ???

Comment: Yes, just edited my code (My code is in French, it's bad, I know, but like this...)

Comment: This not the problem i mean the method name ??

Comment: I've let the french name of the function, but isLaywer() is well defined, and I edited the code...

Comment: Did you update your display? if not you should update it, with this update the label will reload the methods `isDoctor()` and `isLawyer`

Comment: I think I don't, because the display is not refreshed. How do you update the display ? Please not that I don't change my user on the same page I have the problem. So I go to another page, change my user, and go back the page I have my two labels.

Comment: Try to use `validateNow()` as mentioned in this post [Forcing Flex to update the screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120822/forcing-flex-to-update-the-screen)

Comment: Try to use `invalidateDisplayList()` on the view

Comment: Same... I still have the lawyer part displayed when I'm doctor and I use first a lawyer...

Comment: Did you click on some button if you switch from doctor to lawyer ?

Comment: Yeah, actually, I've a popup in the header to change my user. When I click OK, i go back main page and I had my problem in another page than the main one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a bindable boolean var to check the user type, for example :

```
[Bindable] public var isDoctor:Boolean;
[Bindable] public var isLawyer:Boolean;
```

and set their values in your show control routine, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

                [Bindable] public var isDoctor:Boolean;
                [Bindable] public var isLawyer:Boolean; 

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                isDoctor = Session.isDoctor();
                isLawyer = Session.isLawyer();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:Label text="Some Text Lawyer" includeInLayout="{isLawyer}"  visible="{isLawyer}"/>
        <s:Label text="Some Text Doctor" includeInLayout="{isDoctor}"  visible="{isDoctor}"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Well, I have a strange behavior, because I go only once to the creationCompleteHandler. I connect as a lawyer, then as a doctor, and I go only once to the creationCompleteHandler function.

Comment: i mention it just as example on creation complete but you should change the values of your booleans every time a user connect, on connection method for example

Comment: I used your workaround with [Bindable] properties, setting properly each boolean when necessary, and it works better. I don't know why it doesn't work directly... Thank you for the idea